# What are some good online resources we can use?

Tags: discusión

Seems like a lot of answers refer to dictionary definitions that are far more comprehensive than whatever results Google is pushing.  I've also seen a few links to RAE publications that I don't seem to be able to follow.  (I assume they are behind a paywall of some sort, but it may be something I'm doing wrong.)  Also, it would make sense that the most authoritative resources would be in Spanish, but since some of us are trying to learn Spanish ourselves, it would be helpful to have English resources as well.  (Assuming they are available.)

What publicly-available resources ought I consult when asking or answering questions here?

Comment: Answers should be community wiki, perhaps the whole question with answers should be. In any case the #1 resource though it has its flaws is the official Dictionary of the Real Academia Españiol followed by other publications of the RAE including the Diccionario panhispánico de dudas. They are both online.

Comment: @hippietrail: I think community wiki is even [less useful](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1300/1438) on this meta than it is on the main site.  Nobody will gain or lose any reputation and most participants here will get edit privileges soon enough.  But I suppose it doesn't hurt either...

Comment: I thought resource recommendatations are off-topic SE-network wide (even on meta, unfortunately).

Comment: Community wiki does have the advantage of allowing lower-rep users to edit the questions.

Comment: @Richard: Really?  That's certainly news to me.

Comment: I could be wrong, but I've gotten my wrist slapped for it before.  :\

Comment: @Richard That's not so much the advantage as it is the *intent* of Community Wiki. As for the topicality of this question, I'm inclined to let this one slide since it is geared towards the users of the community (rather than the world at large) and a fair amount of the issues with bad recommendations don't apply to Meta sites. There are all sorts of "itemized lists" on Meta sites all around, all for site management and operation. This feels in line with that.

Comment: Marked as a duplicate to the generic [Resources for learning Spanish](http://meta.spanish.stackexchange.com/q/2514/1674)

Comment: @fedorqui'SOstopharming':  A mí me parece una pregunta adecuada para el sitio Meta (independientemente de que en el sitio principal se haya preguntado por recursos para aprender la lengua). Se trata de recursos para responder preguntas o para investigar antes de preguntar, no para aprender. Preguntas análogas en los sitios Meta de [ELU.SE](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2573/) y de [Italian.SE](https://italian.meta.stackexchange.com/q/122/).

Comment: @Charo se discutió extensamente y comparó con distintos sitios. Algunos lo tienen en Meta, otros en el sitio principal. En cualquier caso, tener preguntas análogas en ambos creo que sería la peor opción: mejor concentrar esfuerzos en una. Al fin y al cabo, recursos para responder y recursos para aprender son ideas distintas pero que a la práctica dan lugar a los mismos recursos.

Answer (score 13):

Some resources I know of:

#### Dictionaries

1. The typical resource to get authoritative meanings of Spanish words is the Dictionary of the RAE. To look for a definition (and also useful when writing the url in questions and answers) of some word, namely *wordToSearch*, you can just type:

   > http://lema.rae.es/drae/?val=wordToSearch
2. Diccionario panhispánico de dudas de la RAE

   > http://lema.rae.es/dpd/?key=wordToSearch
3. Diccionario de americanismos de la RAE

   > http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=wordToSearch
4. Diccionario de Dudas y Dificultades de la Lengua Española, de Manuel Seco

   > https://es.scribd.com/doc/151700987/RAE-Seco-Manuel-Diccionario-de-dudas-y-dificultades-de-la-lengua-espanola
5. Mapa de diccionarios de la RAE: consulta simultáneamente seis ediciones representativas del diccionario académico: 1780, 1817, 1884, 1925, 1992 y 2001.

   > http://www.rae.es/recursos/diccionarios/diccionarios-anteriores-1726-1992/mapa-de-diccionarios
6. Real Academia Española - Corpus de Referencia del Español Actual (CREA). Cubre los últimos 25 años de desarrollo del idioma.

   > http://corpus.rae.es/creanet.html
7. Real Academia Española - Corpus Diacrónico del Español (CORDE). Cubre el desarrollo del idioma desde sus inicios hasta un plazo de 25 años desde la fecha actual.

   > http://corpus.rae.es/cordenet.html
8. To get examples of the use of words (English or Spanish), you can use [linguee](http://www.linguee.es/).
9. Another good resource is [www.elcastellano.org](http://www.elcastellano.org/).
10. Diccionario Etimológico en dechile.net

    > http://etimologias.dechile.net/
11. All the resources from Real Academia Española can be found in:

    > http://www.rae.es/recursos

---

#### Pronunciation

- [Forvo.com](http://forvo.com/)

Comment: Si encuentro algún recurso, ¿puedo añadirlo yo mismo?

Comment: El enlace al Mapa de Diccionarios (punto 5) está roto. El correcto es https://apps2.rae.es/ntllet/SrvltGUILoginNtlletPub.

Comment: @karloswitt puedes sugerir modificaciones

Comment: Es el que he puesto, en relación al mapa de Diccionarios.

Comment: @karloswitt lo he actualizado en [Resources for learning Spanish / Recursos para aprender español](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/23618/1674) del sitio principal, que es la pregunta / respuesta que se mantiene actualizada.

Comment: Yo comencé este post con unos pocos recursos, y se ha ido complementando por la comunidad durante más de 10 años. Si tienen nuevos recursos, es genial que los puedan agregar.