# Reviving this resources Meta question

Tags: discusión, recursos, votos-de-reapertura

This meta question: [Resources for answering common questions?](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74/resources-for-answering-common-questions) was closed some time ago as a duplicate of [Resources for Learning Spanish](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2514/resources-for-learning-spanish), but it seems to me this question was more about resources for people specifically searching for *answers* to questions on this site (either to inform themselves before they post, or in answering them itself).

As such I think it is a useful and distinct question worth reopening. I reformatted the sole answer to more explicitly model the "What resources are useful for what type of question" format, and included a number of other resources I though important. If people want to reopen this question, but think such reformatting is [a bit extreme](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74/resources-for-answering-common-questions#comment6843_84), I'll revert it and add it as a separate answer.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I think you did a really great job in the reformatting of the question and its answer. Nonetheless, note that you changed almost everything on it, including the title of the question, which gives us a hint that now the question (and its answer) is a completely different one, and one that may not be what Jon Ericson wanted to ask in the first place.

I would strongly recommend that the question is left as it was before editing (hence leaving there also the "duplicated" mark), and that you ask your own new question (maybe titled "how can we classify the [Resources for Learning Spanish](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2514/resources-for-learning-spanish) according to the type of question being made"). I would have no problem making such good question and answer a featured one. And you will get the credit for it, also. :)